# Не получается собрать проект из-за ошибки no matching function for call to "boost::asio::mutable_buffer(const char&)"

Tags: c++, сервер, boost, udp, buffer

```
//io_context provides core i/o functionality
#include<boost/asio/io_context.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <boost/array.hpp>
#include <boost/asio.hpp>

namespace net = boost::asio;
net::io_context ioc;
using namespace std;
using boost::asio::ip::udp;


int main(){
    try{
    boost::asio::io_context io_context;
    //Create an ip::udp::socket object to receive requests on UDP port 20001.
    udp::socket socket(io_context,udp::endpoint(boost::asio::ip::address().from_string("192.168.19.1"),20001));
    //waiting for a client to connect
    for(;;){
        boost::array<char,250>received_buffer;
        udp::endpoint remote_endpoint;
        socket.receive_from(received_buffer,remote_endpoint);
        string message="Received buffer from sender";
        boost::system::error_code ignored_error;
        socket.send_to(boost::asio::buffer_cast(boost::asio::buffer(message)),remote_endpoint,0);
    }
    }catch(exception &e){
        cerr<<e.what()<<endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Буфер для приема надо создать `boost::asio::buffer(received_buffer)`, на отправку `buffer_cast` лишний.